# how to tell javascript to decrease 50px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> Hi, i'm using bootstrap and i'm trying to make carousel full Screen
>   (measured by users browser height and width).
> but i have a navbar
>   that is fixed-top and come in front of carousel and that makes problem
>   for me. as you see in the image:
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0advO.png)

***jsfiddle Link
https://jsfiddle.net/nbvyeubo/***

**here is my javascript code :**

```
var $item = $('.carousel .item img');
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight);
$item.addClass('full-screen');
$(window).on('resize', function (){
    $wHeight = $(window).height();
    $item.height($wHeight);
});
```

now how can i tell javascript to decrease 50px of the height from top of the img ?

fullscreen class css code :

```
.full-screen {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Comment: Can you include full `html`, `css` at Question and create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry i can't share this projects codes

Comment: How about changing `$item.height($wHeight);` to `$item.height($wHeight - 50);`?

Comment: @guest271314 i use this tutorial to make my carousel fullscreen : [https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/ZbGwqe](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/ZbGwqe)

Comment: @Sander no it doesn't worked

Comment: At which element are you trying to set `css` `height` ?

Comment: @guest271314 .carousel>item img{}

Comment: Within `resize` event `$item.find(".active").css("height", parseFloat($item.find(".active").css("height")) + "px")`? Reset to original `height` if element is not `.active`.

Comment: @guest271314 here is the jsfiddle link : [https://jsfiddle.net/nbvyeubo/](https://jsfiddle.net/nbvyeubo/)

Comment: Are you referencing `#banner` element?

Comment: @guest271314 no my problem is that when i make carousel fullscreen , top part of carousel remain behind the navbar. now when i use 'margin-top: 50px' for my carousel class , it's not full screen any more, how can make it full screen again ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below code will solve your issue.

**css :** 
     `.carousel{ margin-top:50px }`

**js :**
    `var $wHeight = $(window).height() - 50;`

Comment: it does the same job that css does. when i use margin-top, my carousel is not full screen any more ♥

Comment: top part of images are behind the navbar. how can i make images come under the navbar and bottom of the images don't go out of browser?? (for example when i use margin-top:50px for images , they come under the navbar but you should scroll down to see the rest of the images).

Comment: thank you ♥, if you couldn't find any solution, i think making background color of navbar to transparent would be my last soulution, but still would be a problem for this one too, how can i change the bg color of navbar when it collapsed ???

Comment: remove 50px from height also var $wHeight = $(window).height() - 50;

Comment: i add margin-top:50px to carousel and $wHeight = $(window).height() - 50; it become full screen again including navbar . thank you soooo much bro